# Determine the Laurent Series for $f(z)= \frac{e^z}{z-1} , |z| > 1 $

Tags: complex-analysis

*This is a problem from an introductory course in complex analysis for engineers.*

$f$ is analytical everywhere where $z \neq 1$ but since $|z| > 1$ this is already taken care of.

Wrong attempt: We want to find a geometric series that "fit" the function, right? If so, one way is to notice that:

\begin{equation}
f= -\frac{e^z}{1-z} = \frac{1}{z} \frac{e^z}{1 - \frac{1}{z}} = \frac{1}{z} \cdot e^z \frac{1}{1 - \frac{1}{z}} = \frac{1}{z} \cdot e^z \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{z^n} =  e^z \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{z^{n+1}}
\end{equation}

and another way to write this, by starting the series at $n=1$, is
\begin{equation}
e^z \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{z^{n}}
\end{equation}

But this is not the correct solution. Any help appreciated!

**Idea: Am I supposed to multiply the series for $e^z$ and $\frac{1}{z-1} = (z-1)^{-1}$ and then use the fact that the laurent series is unique and identify the coefficients?**

Solution from my textbook: $ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{e}{z^{n}} +  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}( e -  \sum_{k=0}^{n} \frac{1}{k!}) z^n $

Comment: Your work is very nice! I have one question, why didn't you write down the series for $e^z$? That will finish your work.

Comment: Hello. There's an issue with your exercise, there is **no** point mentioned, to determine the Laurent Series around it. The exercise should mention : ***Determine the Laurent series about the point ... when $|z|>1$***

Comment: @Shashi Thank you. I didn't think of that. However, will I get the correct solution if I do that? See solution in the bottom of my post.

Comment: $Rebellos Yes you are right. I think the point are z=0 (see the correct solution in the bottom of my post.).

Comment: @Gustaf I think you get the right answer. I would give it a try since what you have is not a Laurent series.

Comment: @Gustaf If it's around $z=0$ it makes no much sense to determine series. Check my solution below by the way to clear your mind a bit.

Comment: @Rebellos Why wouldn't it make sense to determine series if it's around z=0 ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Truly :

$$f(z)= \frac{e^z}{z-1} =\frac{e^z}{z(1-1/z)}$$

A common geometric series is :

$$\frac{1}{1-w} =\sum_{n=0}^\infty w^n,|w|<1 $$

About the exponential function, it is :

$$e^z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}$$

So, that goes along as :

$$f(z) = \frac{e^z}{z}\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{-n}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{z^n}{n!}\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^{-(n+1)}$$

for $\big|\frac{1}{z}\big| < 1 \Leftrightarrow |z|>1$. Now, if you calculate the common sum of these two, you'll get your result (it's easy) !

On the other hand, if you would want the Laurent Series around $z=1$, you can develop the Laurent series (which is in fact a Taylor series) of $e^z$ about $z=-1$:

$$e^z = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e}{n!}(z-1)^n $$

because $\frac{d^n}{dz^n}e^z=e^z$. Now just divide:

$$\frac{e^z}{z-1}= \frac{1}{z-1} \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e}{n!}(z-1)^n=  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{e}{n!}(z-1)^{n-1}$$

Comment: This is a nice answer, thank you. The only thing I do not understand is the "common sum of these two".

Comment: @Gustaf Make the expression into one sum is what I mean !

Comment: Ah okey, I see! I'm not sure how to do that but I might figure that out.